# Doing a postgresql master-slave on a single machine

Tags: postgresql, docker

I know the concept of the master slave but my question is will it speed up my write and reads if I just set those master and slaves in a single server? Like let us say I set it up in a Docker Daemon, will the read and write be faster when I set it up with two containers? Or will it just be the same with a single postgres container since it will still just use the same linux kernel?

Comment: If both containers use the same filesystem (harddisk), then I would say things will be slower as you double the write load on the system (first the write to the master, and then again the write to the slave).

Comment: Yes, it will be in the same filesystem.. By the way I understand it, the speed of the database relies on the filesystem, so those two database will just spend resource separately doubling the load in the filesystem,  am I thinking right?